# Want to do a fade in if a function() is active/called | Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have the following function in an external Javascript file:

```
function waiting() {                                     
    if (state === WAITING && stateChanged) {            
        stateChanged = false;
        map.draw(ctx);
        //dialog("Press N to start a new game");
    }
}
```

And here the codes in my html file:

```
<div id="pacman">
      <a id="startbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-start" value="">Start new game</a>
      <script src="/pacman/pacman.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/pacman/modernizr-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
```

Javascriptcode in html file ("#startbutton" fade out by starting a new game):

```
var game = document.getElementById("pacman");

    if (Modernizr.canvas && Modernizr.localstorage && 
        Modernizr.audio && (Modernizr.audio.ogg || Modernizr.audio.mp3)) {
      window.setTimeout(function () { PACMAN.init(game, "<?php echo $root; ?>", 100); }, 0);
     } 

    document.getElementById("startbutton").onclick = function(){
        PACMAN.startNewGame();
        $("#startbutton").fadeOut();

    }
```

But now i want if someone is Game Over (`function waiting()` is active) that the `"#startbutton"` fade in (instead of the `dialog("Press N to start a new game");`from the `function waiting()`), so he can play again by clicking again the `"#startbutton"`. I tried different combinations but nothing works. How can i handle it? Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you try `$("#startbutton").fadeIn();`?

Comment: Yes, i tried it in this combinations: 1. `document.getElementById("startbutton"); 
   if  PACMAN.waiting() {
    $("#startbutton").fadeIn();
   }`  2. `document.getElementById("startbutton").onclick = function(){
   if  (PACMAN.startNewGame()) {
    $("#startbutton").fadeOut();
    
   } else if  (PACMAN.waiting()) {
    $("#startbutton").fadeIn();
   }
  }`  Maybe they are errors in the code. In the 1 combination chrome inspector tell me: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: you should load jQuery before the script containing the waiting function. or use vanilla javascript to access the startbutton and simulate a fadein effect (which is doable)

Comment: Did you try putting it in the external js where you have dialog commented out?

Comment: @taha. It doesn't change the situation. In the 1. combination there's always the same error message: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier and in the 2. combination there isn't any error message but there isn't also  any fade out or fade in effect, it means the game is starting but the `"#startbutton"` don't fade out, while with the code ` document.getElementById("startbutton").onclick = function(){
        PACMAN.startNewGame();
        $("#startbutton").fadeOut();

    } ` the fade out of the `"#startbutton"` is working.

Comment: @James. No, how i put in a right way the `"#startbutton"` into the `function waiting()` where the dialog is commented out?

Comment: @Alba your problem can be solved in few minutes if you provide a snippet

Comment: @taha. Now i have the solution. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably get away with jamming it into the external JS file:

```
function waiting() {                                     
    if (state === WAITING && stateChanged) {            
        stateChanged = false;
        map.draw(ctx);
        //dialog("Press N to start a new game");
        $("#startbutton").fadeIn();
    }
}
```

Or, if you want it to be super tidy, you can abstract the jQuery stuff with a function defined in your html file:

```
var game = document.getElementById("pacman");
// rest of your code

function fadeInStartButton() {
  $("#startbutton").fadeIn();
}
```

and then your external JS calls that function (no "untidy" jquery calls in the external js):

```
function waiting() {                                     
    if (state === WAITING && stateChanged) {            
        stateChanged = false;
        map.draw(ctx);
        if (fadeInStartButton) fadeInStartButton();
        else dialog("Press N to start a new game"); // if no function is defined, use the old way
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! :-) Now i will try the super tidy version, so i will learn more. THANKS A LOT!